# using /etc/profile over /home/pi/.profile

Tags: script

Is there an advantage over using `/etc/profile` over `/home/pi/.profile`?
And when to choose which one to use?

Comment: When it comes to configuration files, they usually either work or are completely ignored. Not sure if the former can be called an *advantage*.

Answer (score 2):

- `/etc/profile` is used for all users
- `/home/pi/.profile` is only used for the pi user

So if you only use the `pi` user, no effective difference.

Comment: `/home/pi/.profile` is likely to be ignored altogether if `/home/pi/.bash_profile` is present (which I believe is the case).